# Castlia 3.3 + omnetpp 4.6 on windows 7- permission denied

Tags: windows, bash, omnet++

I have compiled both castalia and omnet and everything was right but 
when running simulation using command line I got this error:

***/c/Castalia/Simulations/radioTest$ ../../bin/Castalia
bash: ../../bin/Castalia: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: Permission denied***

I installed python 2.6 in usr/bin path. but still has that error.

I tried #! usr/bin/env, but again I got same error.

how i can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general Castalia is not supported under Windows, and any success people have running it is based on homebrews (custom solutions based on their configuration). The more reliable solution would be to run Ubuntu (perhaps on a virtual machine in Windows). Mac OS X works fine too.

Seeing your `bash` tag, I am not sure how you got to run bash on Windows (Cygwin?), but if you have a bash shell you can run `which python` to see where python resides on your system.  If it's something other than /usr/bin/python then you can try changing the shebang line to the correct location. Or you can try `#!/usr/bin/env python` (notice the python executable after the path).

Also make sure you have the permission to run Python as the user you are logged in! How would you run any python script from command line?

Finally it is recommended that you have Python 2.7 installed, but it *may* run fine with 2.6 too.